# Pre-Populating Date field on document before signing

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement where I need to populate my applicant's DOB from Salesforce record on my application. While signing applicant will check his DOB and fill in all required fields and sign the application.

To achieve this I followed *https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DfS-How-to-write-a-date-back-to-Salesforce* and succeeded with prepopulating.

But the problem now is that **I need to display the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format only** but the DOB is prepopulating in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  *(Note: I have a validation rule in place for that specific format.)*

How can I change the prepopulating date format while loading the Application?

Suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Suma.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the date format by going to the DocuSign web app, logging in and going to the top-right menu to **My Preferences** and selecting **Regional Settings** from the menu at the left. It looks like this:

[image]

However, a date filed in DocuSign is always the date when the document is signed. For DOB you would need to use a text field which can be pre-populated (a date field cannot be pre-populated).